# Prove if $T\in\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathrm{d}T/\mathrm{d}x=0$ then $T$ is the constant distribution.

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

> Prove if $T\in\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathrm{d}T/\mathrm{d}x=0$
>   then $T$ is the constant distribution.

I am having some problems both proving this problem, as well as understanding exactly what I am supposed to prove. I guess the starting point is done like this. The statement

$$
\langle T' , \phi \rangle = \langle T , \phi' \rangle = 0
\tag{1}
$$

Implises

$$
\langle T , \phi \rangle = C \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(x) \,\mathrm{d}x
\tag{2}
$$

Where $\phi$ is the standard testfunction, and $C$ is a constant deppendant on the particular distribution. However I am not sure how to prove that $(2)$ follows from $(1)$.

There is a solution for this problem, [here](https://wiki.math.ntnu.no/_media/tma4170/2012v/foursoln.pdf) (page 2). However I was completely lost after the first few lines. Could anyone help me start writing a proof for this statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A summary of the proof in the link:

Fix a test function $\eta$ with integral $1$ and define $C=\langle T,\eta \rangle$. You have to do this somewhere to identify the constant.

Then, given a test function $\phi$, find a test function $\psi$ such that

$$\psi'(x)=\phi(x)-\eta(x) \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(y) dy.$$

One thing the proof in the link does not do is to prove that the resulting $\psi$ is actually a test function. But it is: in particular, its support is contained in $[m,M]$ where $m=\inf \left ( \text{supp} \phi \cup \text{supp} \eta \right )$ and $M=\sup \left ( \text{supp} \phi \cup \text{supp} \eta \right )$. You should check this, as it is an important part of the proof.

Then you use linearity and the definition of the distributional derivative:

$$\langle T',\psi \rangle = 0 = -\langle T,\psi' \rangle = -\langle T,\phi \rangle + \langle T,\eta \rangle \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(y) dy = -\langle T,\phi \rangle + C \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(y) dy$$

and the result follows by rearranging.

Comment: So basically a constant distribution is $\langle T_f , \phi \rangle = C \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ where the $C$ is dependent on the test function?

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar $C$ does *not* depend on the test function, that's the point. $C$ comes from $\eta$ which does not depend on $\phi$.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar I had a typo in my previous version of my comment, sorry.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar Intuitively a constant distribution is the distribution given by integration against a constant function.

Comment: Right! ${}{}{}$

Comment: why ⟨T,η⟩ is a constant?

Comment: @user1500178 $T $ is given and fixed while I decided that $\eta $ is fixed. So the application is fixed.

Comment: @user1500178 Maybe you're asking "why does $\langle T,\eta \rangle$ only depend on $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \eta(x) dx$, and not on specifics of $\eta$"?" Well, I didn't assume that, I just picked $\eta$ "at random". But I expected that, and indeed this proof shows it.